# (CreateMap Linq C# ) MapFrom conditions in List

Tags: c#, linq, automapper, mapper

In my CreateMap function, i'm trying to set a bool in the dest object to True, if a Guid in the source is something specific.
It gets tricky because the guid im trying to compare, is located in an object, in a list of objects, in the src object. (see code if it does not make sense).

My CreateMap function (*i think this is the problem*)

```
CreateMap<User, UserRoleResponse>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.OrganisationAdministrator, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Organisations.FirstOrDefault().RoleId.Equals("00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001")));
```

Src object (User.cs):

```
public class User
{
    
    public List<UserOrganisation> Organisations { get; set; }

    *** other props removed for irrelevans *** 
}

public class UserOrganisation
{
    public Guid UserId { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }
    public Guid RoleId { get; set; }
    public Role Role { get; set; }
}
```

The dest object:

```
public class UserRoleResponse
{
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool OrganisationAdministrator { get; set; }
}
```

To recap, my use case is:

If the RoleId within *UserOrganisation.cs* is == "--0001", the *OrganisationAdministrator* within *UserRoleResponse.cs* should be true.

Is it possible that I should iterate through the list of *Organisations* in the *CreateMap* ?

Comment: Have you tried to do that without AM?

Comment: The rest of the system i build on AM, so im told to keep the convention. If i were to do it without, how and where would you reckon ?

Comment: I do not see LINQ query to make the same without AM.

Comment: Equals may not work if you try to compare Guid and String. Try either:
`RoleId.ToString().Equals("00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001")`
or
`RoleId.Equals(new Guid("00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001"))`